# How to find IP address of application (for instance Drive)?

Tags: web-services, terminal, ip-address

I am using an app called SelfControl. It blocks all Internet traffic as not to distract me, but the app allows you to make a whitelist of sites or services that can be accessed. However, although sometimes the IP range is mentioned on an app's website, this is not always correct, and the app is still blocked.

So, using Terminal or any other default program, how do I find the exact stream URL or IP address a particular app is using (for instance Drive or Spotify)?

PS. I considered SuperUser, but as the solution may involve a few lines of code I thought SO was more appropriate.